# Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I really need some help in hibernate, and i search all questions,but it didn't work.

My question is strange,at least I think so. In my project, i want to use entity class, hibernate xml mapping file(*.hbm.xml) and hibernate configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml) to create table in mysql database. Strange that I have only one table can not be created, and other tables can be created successfully.

OK,These are my project code, i think these information might be used.

```
cart.java

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Ning
 *
 */
public class Cart implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> shopItems = new HashMap<>();

    public Cart() {}

    public Cart(User user, Map<Integer, Integer> shopItems) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.shopItems = shopItems;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Map<Integer, Integer> getShopItems() {
        return shopItems;
    }
    public void setShopItems(Map<Integer, Integer> shopItems) {
        this.shopItems = shopItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cart [id=" + id + ", user=" + user + ", shopItems=" + shopItems + "]";
    }

}


<!------cart.hbm.xml----->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2017-4-30 9:23:54 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.eshop.design.model.Cart" table="CART">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="com.eshop.design.model.User" fetch="join">
            <column name="USER" />
        </many-to-one>
        <map name="shopItems">
            <key column="CART_ID"></key>
            <index column="PRODUCT_ID" type="java.lang.Integer"></index>
            <element column="NUMBER" type="java.lang.Integer"></element>
        </map>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>



Order.java

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Order implements Serializable{


    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> shopItems = new HashMap<>();
    private Date date;
    private Status status;
    private String remark;

    public Order() {}
    public Order(User user, Map<Integer, Integer> shopItems, Date date, Status status, String remark) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.shopItems = shopItems;
        this.date = date;
        this.status = status;
        this.remark = remark;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Map<Integer, Integer> getShopItems() {
        return shopItems;
    }
    public void setShopItems(Map<Integer, Integer> shopItems) {
        this.shopItems = shopItems;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }
    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [id=" + id + ", user=" + user + ", shopItems=" + shopItems + ", date=" + date + ", status="
                + status + ", remark=" + remark + "]";
    }
}

<!-------order.hbm.xml----->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2017-4-30 9:23:54 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.eshop.design.model.Order" table="ORDER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="com.eshop.design.model.User" fetch="join">
            <column name="USER" />
        </many-to-one>
        <map name="shopItems">
            <key column="ORDER_ID"></key>
            <index column="PRODUCT_ID" type="java.lang.Integer"></index>
            <element column="NUMBER" type="java.lang.Integer"></element>
        </map>
        <property name="date" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="DATE" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="status" class="com.eshop.design.model.Status" fetch="join">
            <column name="STATUS" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="remark" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="REMARK" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<!-----user.java------>

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class User implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String login;
    private String pass;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private Double assets;

    // Constructors
    /** default constructor */
    public User() {}
    /** full constructor */
    public User( String login, String pass, String name, String phone, String address, Double assets) {
        super();
        this.login = login;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.assets = assets;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Double getAssets() {
        return assets;
    }
    public void setAssets(Double assets) {
        this.assets = assets;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", login=" + login + ", pass=" + pass + ", name=" + name + ", phone=" + phone
                + ", address=" + address + ", assets=" + assets + "]";
    }

}


<!-----user.hbm.xml---->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 2017-4-30 9:23:54 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.eshop.design.model.User" table="USER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="login" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LOGIN" />
        </property>
        <property name="pass" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PASS" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PHONE" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ADDRESS" />
        </property>
        <property name="assets" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="ASSETS" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>



<!-- I config the data source and session factory in the spring's configuration file applicationContext.xml-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="user" value="${user}"></property> 
        <property name="password" value="${password}"></property>
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClass}"></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbcUrl}"></property>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${initialPoolSize}" />
    </bean>

<!-- SessionFactory  config -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
        <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:com/eshop/design/model/*.hbm.xml"></property>
    </bean>

<!----hibernate.cfg.xml--->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the first time I have asked questions here, some formats may be unsatisfactory.

Thanks in advance and forget my  poor English.

Comment: I suppose user is the keyword in db. Change column name to user_id in hbm.xml

Comment: what table does not persist on database. Suppose you can share the `user.java` pojo and hibernate cfg.xml also.

Comment: I do not know how to add code in the comment, so add some information in the original text. And the exception information could click **http://blog.csdn.net/loserkids/article/details/71003408**.

Comment: The order table can not be created successfully!